# Why does my DLL require my program to have a specific name?

Tags: c++, dll

I've created some classes in a C++ application that I've developed that allow for third party developers to create their own DLL that subclasses off one my objects and have their subclass get loaded by the application through that DLL at runtime. This part all works.

The problem comes in when the name of the application executable is changed. Say I pass this application, call it "App.exe", to tester and he renames it to  App-02.exe to distinguish it from another version he's tested. When App-02.exe attempts to load the DLL it throws the error: 
"The program can't start because App.exe is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."

There's an obvious solution, just don't rename the executable. But why should the DLL even care what the program loading it is called?

Comment: Is your DLL calling back into the executable?

Comment: The subclass in the DLL does call the parent constructor and uses some of the member functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the base class is defined inside App.exe, so you've got a circular dependency in your binaries (app.exe -> plug-in.dll -> app.exe). You can break this cycle by using the dependency inversion principle. Basically, move your base class out of app.exe and into a new .dll. Then you have something like this: app.exe -> plug-in-api.dll, plug-in.dll -> plug-in-api.dll.

Of course, if you do this, your tester might just rename plug-in-api.dll and everything would break again.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle

Comment: Is the DLL actually loading a second instance of my main app? That seems hideously inefficient

Comment: I don't believe so. It would just increment the reference count on the application's image. 

An .exe is not really any different from a .dll except that it specifies an entry point (e.g., WinMain or whatever wrapper is placed around WinMain.). The tools that can dump the contents of a DLL work the same on an EXE. And it is possible to LoadLibrary for a .exe (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1045674/Load-EXE-as-DLL-Mission-Possible)

Comment: If you LoadLibrary("someFile") a first time, and then immediately LoadLibrary("someFile") again, Windows will set the reference count for "someFile" to 1, and then to 2.

If you then FreeLibrary(the-hinstance-from-loadLibrary) twice, Windows will set the referenceCount for "someFile" to 1, then to 0, at which time it will actually unload the DLL.

Comment: Did this answer explain your problem? If so would you mind giving the old checkmark? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, it was my first question, I didn't realize about check marking.